# Why is it is printing two times?

Tags: flutter, build

I have placed print command for printing value of variable inside build method...but while hot restart it is showing two times in consul output...why.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
   bool value=true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(value);
    return Checkbox(
        value: value,
        onChanged: (value){
          setState(() {
            this.value=value!;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your setState calls happen within the same frame, then there's no issue.

The widget will rebuild once and only once.

Once a widget is marked as needing build, all subsequent calls to setState will do nothing but call the callback until a frame is scheduled and the build is done.

You can use conditional statement to check unwanted builds.